# Is heat death absolutely and really inevitable?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, entropy, time, universe

As the second law of thermodynamics indicates, entropy would continue to grow in the universe until it reaches a maximal value (in an expanding universe with a cosmological constant, like ours) or even an infinite value (for an expanding universe without a cosmological constant).

However, I have been told that the second law of thermodynamics *could* be violated in some special contexts or if we would wait an infinite time, since it is an statistical law.

So, could entropy be reversed spontaneously for some periods of time? If not, could there be other mechanisms that would avoid the continuous increase of entropy, and thus heat death?

Answer (score 1):

While this entire question is entirely speculative, I will give my two cents that the second law has no known exceptions, at least on average. In statistical mechanics it is possible to have microscopic violations of the second law, but the law of averages and the sheer density of the state spaces involved means that we will never see anything resembling persistent or large-scale deviations from the expected behavior.

As you are likely aware, the second law states that an isolated system will necessarily increase or retain its entropy as it undergoes spontaneous processes towards a state of equilibrium. But I want to focus on the qualifier that the second law applies to isolated systems for a moment. Again, you are likely aware that an isolated physical system is one which does not exchange matter or energy with any outside surroundings. But we have no means of verifying if or to what degree this is true for the universe as a whole. If our universe is capable of interacting with some external universes, perhaps, then we have no reason to assume isolation and the second law need not apply. But we have no reasonable means of verifying the existence of multiple universes, and Occam’s razor seems to suggest that this is a rather unreasonable claim without evidence. A theist may posit that any non-deistic “God” (however conceived) would constitute a violation of the isolation of the universe, though that takes us even farther from physics than our multiverse speculation.

In either case, there is then no need to speculate heat death of the universe, as we would have no obvious mechanism driving it. But then we just get into other speculative modern cosmologies such as variable cosmological constants, big crunches, etc. I generally suggest that pondering this should only be an armchair activity, as it is not particularly fruitful to wildly speculate about things none of us will ever experience.

Comment: Please consider using paragraph breaks to separate these good points!

Comment: I apologize, I know the formatting of that was terrible. I wrote it on my phone. Let me edit it to try to improve formatting.